# Connect symbol layer from Layers Panel to function

Tags: pyqgis, style, table-of-contents

If I create a simple function:

```
def print_me():
    print 'Clicked!'
```

and I switch off the symbology for `Elephant` as shown below:

[image: Example]

I would like the function to run. What would be ideal is if we can determine whether the symbology is checked or not so that the function can be expanded:

```
def print_me(checked):
    if checked:
        print 'On!'
    else:
        print 'Off!'
```

Is it possible to connect the signal emitted from a style layer (from the Layers Panel) to a function and determine if it is checked or not?

---

**Edit:**

I used the following to identify the layer's renderer state but can't seem to find a way to connect this to the function:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for x in layer.rendererV2().categories():
    print x.renderState()

>>>True
>>>True 
>>>False
>>>True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there's another way, but this is how I'd do that:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, QObject
from functools import partial

layer = iface.activeLayer()
ltl = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer( layer.id() )
ltm = iface.layerTreeView().model()
legendNodes = ltm.layerLegendNodes( ltl ) # This gives us access to each node
for ln in legendNodes:
    ln.dataChanged.connect( partial( changed, ln ) )

def changed(ln):
    print ln.data( Qt.DisplayRole ), ("Checked" if ln.data( Qt.CheckStateRole ) == 2 else "Unchecked")
```

Just select a layer and run the code. As soon as you update the layer's symbology, all connections will be lost and you will need to set them again.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you and thanks also to introducing me to `functools.partial` :)

Comment: Oh yes, they are super useful for passing extra parameters to your SLOTs.